# android-grouping radiobuttons in such case

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

in my app I inflate a view from layout folder:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#468966"
android:layout_height="40dp">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/optionText"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#002F2F"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/radio"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

and add it dynamically to a linearlayout. now, how may i group the radio buttons of these views so that only one of them can be selected at a time?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a RadioGroup control in your XML file.

```
<RadioGroup 
android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Then you can add to it dynamically in this manner

```
RadioGroup rgp= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
 RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
 RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
 radioButton.setText("new"+i); radioButton.setId("rbtn"+i); 
rprms= new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms); 
}
```

Comment: `First you need to have a RadioGroup control in your XML file.`. which xml file?!

Comment: Where you will be adding the radio button dynamically for grouping